# Angular Post Request Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular coming from Java and I'm having a tough time figuring this out. I'm getting a "ReferenceError: user is not defined" at the first if statement, but in my other controller I'm declaring a variable the exact same way and it works fine. The documentation for this error seems to be attempting to use variables that are out of the scope or haven't been declared; where is the inconsistency here?

Here is the form that gets injected into ng-view:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="controller.register()">
  <div ng-show="controller.user.username.length > 20">Username must be 20 characters or less.</div>
  <br>
  <div ng-show="controller.user.username = null">Username is blank.</div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="controller.user.username" placeholder="Choose a username." />
  <br/>
  <div ng-show="controller.user.password = null">Password is blank.</div>
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="controller.user.password" placeholder="Choose a password." />
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div>{{controller.msg}}</div>
</form>
```

and here is the relevant part of the controller:

```
wishingWell.controller('register', function($http, $location, $rootScope) {

  var noerrors = false;
  var self = this;
  self.user = {};
  self.msg = undefined;


  if (self.user.username != null && self.user.username.length <= 20 && self.user.password != null) {
    noerrors = true;
  }

  self.register = function() {

    if (noerrors) {
      $http.post('register', user).success(function(response) {

        if (response.data.code == "200") {
          $rootScope.authenticated = true;
          $location.path("/user-home");
        } else {
          msg = response.data.msg;
          $location.path("/sign-up");
        }

      });
    } else {
      $location.path("/sign-up");
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the login controller that declares the variable in a similar way:

```
wishingWell.controller('navigation',

  function($rootScope, $http, $location) {

    var self = this;

    var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

      var headers = credentials ? {
        authorization: "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
      } : {};

      $http.get('user', {
        headers: headers
      }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.name) {
          $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        } else {
          $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        }
        callback && callback();
      }, function() {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        callback && callback();
      });

    }

    authenticate();
    self.credentials = {};
    self.login = function() {
      authenticate(self.credentials, function() {
        if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
          $location.path("/");
          self.error = false;
        } else {
          $location.path("/login");
          self.error = true;
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

Comment: In your ng-show's you have = instead of ==.  Is that really what you have in your code? If so, that might be the problem. Whenever Angular evaluates the ng-show you are setting the username and the password to be null.

Comment: I didn't realize that was a "setter". From what I've seen it evaluates as a boolean condition and then displays that div if true. Does it do this while also acting as a setter if you use "="?

Comment: it will first evaluate the expression and the result will be used for ng-show. So `ng-show="controller.user.username = null"` sets controller.user.username to null, and then uses the value for ng-show: So you are basically doing a `ng-show="null"` which is falsy and will never show.